# How to change NetBeans charset?

Tags: netbeans, character-encoding

I researched on google and I found this [article](http://wiki.clinicaltools.com/NetBeans:UTF-8_Character_Set), but my codes still being saved as ansi.
[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net) has a feature to change/convert the code charset, does someone know if there exists any option in Netbeans?

**nebeans.conf**:

netbeans_default_options="-J-Dorg.glassfish.v3.installRoot=\"E:\Programs\sges-v3-prelude\" -J-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=\"E:\Programs\AppServer\" -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

**project.properties**:

```
include.path=${php.global.include.path}
source.encoding=UTF-8
src.dir=.
tags.asp=false
tags.short=true
web.root=.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

While Boro is correct, in a sense so is Krishna. UTF-8 is designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII. So if you save a file in UTF-8, and use only characters that can be found in ASCII, you essentially have an ASCII file. UTF-8 extends ASCII encoding to give a way to encode other characters using more than one byte if necessary.

Answer (score -3):

Just FYI- <strike>UTF8 characters map on to US-ANSI.</strike> Meaning: 'A'(ASCII value 65) in utf8 is the same.
So you would not know the difference if your program is written in ANSI or UTF-8.

Edit - Pardon my English. US-ANSI characters map on to UTF8 character set. What I mean is:
US ANSI ASCII from values 0 to 127 is same as that of 0 to 127 of UTF8 and vice-verse is not true.

Comment: There are thousands of special characters that don't map to ANSI.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa, whoa, whoa, UTF-8 does not map 1:1 to ASCII. UTF-8 has around 100,000 characters that do not map to ASCII.

Comment: Yes! completely agreed. I should be careful with English. Thanks for pointing out.